# How to draw a list of images?

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I found an example with strings

```
...
List<String> inventory = new List<>(skin), sell = new List<>(skin);
inventory.setItems("Axe", "Fuel", "Helmet", "Flux Capacitor", "Shoes", "Hammer", "Trash Can", "The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy", "Cucumber");

Table table = new Table(skin);

table.add("Inventory");
table.add("Merchant").row();
table.add(inventory).expand().fill();
table.add(sell).expand().fill();
...
```

result:

[image]

https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/somelibgdxtests/src/d787e98e84647d06ffbe9add3165e87bcabef7e3/core/src/net/dermetfan/someLibgdxTests/screens/DragAndDropTutorial.java?fileviewer=file-view-default

How to replace strings with images?

My code:

```
...
List<Image> inventory = new List<>(skin), sell = new List<>(skin);
inventory.setItems(Image(texture1), Image(texture2), Image(texture3));
...
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You replace the text with an Image class e.g

```
table.add(new Image(new TextureRegionDrawable(texRegion)));
```

texRegion should be a TextureRegion you have already loaded

Comment: I can add one image. How to add a list of images? Necessary for "drag and drop". Link in question, up.

Comment: I believe the List uses the toString() function to get the string to show in the list and as such will not draw an image as you desire. You could extend the list class and override the draw/drawItem methods